# Disallowing setting array properties with TSLint

Tags: tslint

I was wondering if there is a TSLint rule with which I can disallow the following code:

```js
var arr = [1, 2];
//the line below should be disallowed
arr.prop1 = "3";
//because arr now has array elements and object properties
```

I want to disallow this because it prevents `arr` from being fully serialized with `JSON.stringify`, because `JSON.stringify` will serialize `arr` into `[1, 2]`.

I have looked at the [TSLint rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) but wasn't able to find a rule for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a TSLint rule for this, which is available on GitHub and NPM:

- https://github.com/leroydev/no-setting-array-properties-rule
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/no-setting-array-properties-rule

It can be used like this:

- Install it using `npm install no-setting-array-properties-rule --save-dev`.
- Add it to your `tslint.json`, like this:

  ```
  {
     "rulesDirectory": [
         "../node_modules/no-setting-array-properties-rule/dist/src"
     ],
     "rules": {
         "no-setting-array-properties": true
     }
  }
  ```

**Edit:**

It can be implemented by just setting `noImplicitAny: true` too, for my project this wasn't an acceptable solution, but that's the easy fix.